# Saving a UIView for next launch (not as an image)

Tags: iphone, uiview, nscoder

I am building an app with several `UIViews` which are generated dynamically, based on user inputs.  These `UIViews` may contain labels, images and text.  They take some time to generate so I would like the user to be able to load them up quickly on future launches of the app without having to redraw them again.  One requirement is that they need to keep their interactive state so the user can continue to edit them.

I looked into `NSKeyedArchiver` but this doesn't seem to support `UIImage`. Also, I can't save it as PNG since I would like to retain their interactive state.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider keeping the model of your data separate from the interface.  You can then use this stored model to generate the interface.  I know you specifically said that you don't want to do this.  However, any built in method is going to have to rebuild the UIViews in exactly the same way.

If the processing of the model data is the issue, try to come up with a way to efficiently represent the state of the interface so that you don't have to start from scratch.  However, that will be a lot more work.